# Problema en la respuesta de las teclas de controles de mi juego de snake, Java, GUI

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jframe

Tengo mi juego de snake dividido en varias clases, las que me generan problemas son: Controles, ContenidoJuego (Contiene el pintado y la lógica del juego), VentanaJuegoGUI (Una ventana básica en la cual estan extras y dentro de esta, en un panel, esta el juego).
La ventana del juego muestra correctamente las opciones extras y el juego, pero cuando se llama al juego para que este dentro de esta ventana no responen los controles
'''

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class VentanaJuegoGUI extends JFrame {

private JLabel titulo;
private JLabel textoMarcador;
private JLabel textoTiempoJuego;
private JButton botonReinicioJuego;
private ContenidoJuego contenidoJuego; 

private Timer tiempoJuego;
private int segundos;

public VentanaJuegoGUI() {
    setTitle("Snake");
    setSize(1000, 620);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Configuracion del timer del tiempo de juego
    tiempoJuego = new Timer();
    
    tiempoJuego.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(contenidoJuego.confirmarEstadoJuego()){
                segundos++;
                actualizarTiempoJuego(); // Método para mostrar o actualizar el tiempo donde lo necesites
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

    // Configurar el panel de juego
    contenidoJuego = new ContenidoJuego();
    contenidoJuego.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Configurar el título
    titulo = new JLabel("Snake");
    titulo.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 60));
    titulo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // Configurar el marcador
    textoMarcador = new JLabel("Marcador: 0");
    textoMarcador.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 36));

    // Configurar el tiempo de juego
    textoTiempoJuego = new JLabel("Tiempo de Juego: 0:00");
    textoTiempoJuego.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 36));

    // Botón para reiniciar el juego
    botonReinicioJuego = new JButton("Reiniciar Juego");
    botonReinicioJuego.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    botonReinicioJuego.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            contenidoJuego.reiniciarJuego(); // Define el método en ContenidoJuego para reiniciar el juego
            segundos = 0;
        }
    });


    // Panel para contener el título, el marcador y el tiempo de juego
    JPanel panelExtras = new JPanel();
    panelExtras.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
    panelExtras.add(titulo);
    panelExtras.add(textoMarcador);
    panelExtras.add(textoTiempoJuego);
    panelExtras.add(botonReinicioJuego);

    // Panel para contener el panel de juego
    JPanel panelContenidoJuego = new JPanel();
    panelContenidoJuego.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panelContenidoJuego.add(contenidoJuego, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Panel para contener panelExtras y panelContenidoJuego
    JPanel panelContenedor = new JPanel();
    panelContenedor.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panelContenedor.add(panelExtras, BorderLayout.WEST);
    panelContenedor.add(panelContenidoJuego, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Agregar el panelContenedor al centro de la ventana
    add(panelContenedor, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        new VentanaJuegoGUI();
    });
}

private void actualizarTiempoJuego() {
    int minutos = segundos / 60;
    int segundosRestantes = segundos % 60;
    String tiempoFormateado = String.format("Tiempo de Juego: %02d:%02d", minutos, segundosRestantes);
    textoTiempoJuego.setText(tiempoFormateado);
}

}
```

'''

Los controles son manejados por `KeyAdapter` haciendo un Override en `keyPressed` a las teclas 'wasd' para moverse
'''

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Controles extends KeyAdapter {
private ContenidoJuego contenidoJuego; 

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    boolean confirmadorMov;
    switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
        case 'w':
            confirmadorMov = contenidoJuego.confirmarMovimiento('w');
            if (confirmadorMov) {
                contenidoJuego.cambiarDireccion('w');
            }
            break;
        case 's':
            confirmadorMov = contenidoJuego.confirmarMovimiento('s');
            if (confirmadorMov) {
                contenidoJuego.cambiarDireccion('s');
            }
            break;
        case 'a':
            confirmadorMov = contenidoJuego.confirmarMovimiento('a');
            if (confirmadorMov) {
                contenidoJuego.cambiarDireccion('a');
            }
            break;
        case 'd':
            confirmadorMov = contenidoJuego.confirmarMovimiento('d');
            if (confirmadorMov) {
                contenidoJuego.cambiarDireccion('d');
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

}
```

'''

Comment: Te genera problemas? Vaya... Lo siento mucho por ti, ojalá puedas arreglarlo. Si quieres que te ayudemos a arreglarlo, podrías empezar por decirnos qué problemas te genera. Si buscas ayuda lo primero es especificar **con qué buscas ayuda** :) Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO. Sé que es un coñazo leer documentación y que preferirías que te ayudemos sin más, pero sinceramente, si quieres ser programador te vas a hartar de leer documentación, y si quieres que nos esforcemos en ayudarte, esfuérzate primero en hacer una pregunta de calidad :)

Comment: Decir "no funciona" o "no responde" no aporta nada de información. Qué error te da? Has depurado el código? Ves si realmente se está ejecutando el código que no hace nada? Danos una pista de por dónde empezar a mirar! Puedes editar tu pregunta para añadir la información necesaria usando el enlace [edit]. Además, no estaría de más indicar qué has intentado hacer para solucionarlo, así no tenemos que probar cosas que ya hayas probado tu y no funcionen!